# ANDROID :: TextView Height fixed size doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I sets TextView **Height 30dp** initial **font size is 15sp**

when I change (@+id/txtSubject1) to **10sp** I want its Height remain **30dp**.

However, it change along with the font size.

(I found out that when I change (@+id/txtTime1) to 10sp, its Height is what I want but I don't need this textView to be the same size)

Can I achieve this issue??

THANK!

HERE is my XML

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtTime1" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="15dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@color/bg_greyTransparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtSubject1" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:minHeight="30dp" android:text="ENGLISH IV"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:maxHeight` to limit the height.

Answer (score 0):

As my guess. The TextView's height is till 30 dip. You can change the TextView background to test it. Text's size is changed but TextView's size is remain. 
If I am wrong. You should use : android:minHeigh attribute.

Comment: Actually i have try minHight but when decrease textsize background height become smaller

Answer (score 0):

So, This is what I want...

fixed height at parent instead and let its child height match_parent

and set **android:gravity="center|center_vertical"**

In conclusion, I can set any font size and TextView's height remain the same

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtTime1" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="15dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@color/bg_greyTransparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtSubject1" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:minHeight="30dp" android:text="ENGLISH IV"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```